# wp_insert_post at same time as saving post results in 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: wp-insert-post

I'm currently trying to create/update one post while also saving the current post that I'm on. It's all happening here:

```
add_action('save_post', 'wysiwyg_save_meta');
function wysiwyg_save_meta(){
    global $post;
    $editor_id = WYSIWYG_EDITOR_ID;
    $meta_key = WYSIWYG_META_KEY;

    if(isset($_REQUEST[$editor_id])) {
        update_post_meta($post->ID, WYSIWYG_META_KEY, $_REQUEST[$editor_id]);

        $thankYouPost = get_thank_you_post($post->ID);

        $postArgs = array(
            'post_content'   => $_REQUEST[$editor_id], 
            'post_name'      => 'thank-you',
            'post_title'     => "Thank You",
            'post_status'    => $post->post_status,
            'post_type'      => 'landing_page',
            'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
        );

        if ($thankYouPost->ID) {
            $postArgs['ID'] = $thankYouPost->ID;
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
        wp_reset_query();
        wp_insert_post($postArgs);
        wp_reset_postdata();
        wp_reset_query();
    }
}
```

Now, this works and saves both pages, but it doesn't seem like it's actually working. The page just sits and tries to load and eventually I get back a 502 Bad Gateway error. However, manually refreshing the page shows me that the action was successful.

What could be causing this? Any more information I will be happy to provide. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Otto - it's going to cause an infinite loop. The solution is to unhook your function before you do a wp_insert_post and then hook it back on afterwards.

```
remove_action('save_post', 'wysiwyg_save_meta');
wp_insert_post($postArgs);
add_action('save_post', 'wysiwyg_save_meta');
```

Answer (score 1):

Hate to point out the obvious but:

```
add_action('save_post', 'wysiwyg_save_meta');
function wysiwyg_save_meta(){
...
        wp_insert_post($postArgs);
...
}
```

That's an infinite loop.

The save_post action is called at the end of wp_insert_post. So you're just looping around in circles, digging an ever deeper hole of calling your function and then wp_insert_post over and over again, until you eat up all available memory or the process times out.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to just add a new save_post action containing my wp_insert_post function? Or do I need to test for something completely different and then call wp_insert_post?

Comment: I think the real point is to not call `wp_insert_post` from inside a function hooked to the `save_post` action at all. You're making a recursive loop here. You need to either break the loop or not start it to begin with.